# Finding a group G and normal subgroup N such that G/N is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G$ is a group and $N$ is a proper non-abelian normal subgroup of $G$. Moreover, $G/N$ is abelian. Give examples for $G$ and $N$.

This was the question. I've come up with the group $G= \mathbb R \cup 
\{ i,j,k,-1,1,-i,-j,-k \} $. Choose $N=\{ i,j,k,-1,1,-i,-j,-k \}$.

Then $N$ is non abelian as $ij=k$ but $ji=-k$. Moreover, $N$ is a normal subgroup. For any $g \in G$ and $a \in N$, we have two cases. If $g \in \mathbb R$ then $g^{-1}ag \in N$ as for any $r \in \mathbb R$ and $x \in N$, $rx=xr$. If $g \in N$, then $g^{-1}ag \in N$.

And now consider $G/ N = \{ aN : a \in G \}$. Let $aN, bN \in G/N$.
We split into cases:

**Case 1:** $a \in \mathbb R$, $b \in \mathbb R$

$aNbN=NabN=NbaN=bNaN$, as for any $r \in \mathbb R$ and $a \in N$ we have $ar=ra$ and $\mathbb R$ is commutative.

**Case 2:** $a \in N$ and $b \in N$

We have $aNbN=NN=N=bNaN$

**Case 3:** $a \in N$ and $b \in \mathbb R$

We have $aNbN=NbN=bNN=bN=bNaN=bNN=bN$.

This was my attempt to find such $G$ and $N$. However, i'm just worried about the fact that I did not show for any $r \in \mathbb R$ and $ x \in N$, $rx=xr$.

Can you spot identify reasoning? Am I right about the choice of $G$ and $N$?

Comment: $\mathbb R \cup 
\{ i,j,k,-1,1,-i,-j,-k \}$ is not a group.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of finite groups which work. The union of $\mathbb R$ with your finite set is not a group under either addition or multiplication (not closed under either - and it would have to be addition if you include $0\in \mathbb R$ - there is a construction related to your idea which gives a non-abelian multiplicative group) and you haven't specified what the group operation is supposed to be.

Comment: My guess is that you mean the multiplicative group of the quaternion algebra!

Comment: My advice is to start small. The smallest nonabelian group is $S_3$. Can you find a group that has $S_3$ as a proper normal subgroup, with abelian quotient? Think *small*.

Comment: @pigeon Well, yes, I've done a major mistake. What if we modify that union as, $\mathbb R \cup \{ ai,bj,cj,1,-1,-ai, -bi, -ci, k : a,b,c,k \in \mathbb R \} $ and define usual multiplication as on the quaternion group, would it be a correct example?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Would $A_4$ work?

Comment: How about $A_4$ as $N$ with $G$ = ....

Comment: @GerryMyerson Excellent hint.

Comment: $A_4$ doesn't have a subgroup isomorphic to $S_3$. In fact, it has no subgroup of order $12$. I guess the set of all things of the shapes $a$, $ai$, $aj$, $ak$ with $a$ a nonzero real and with the usual quaternion relations $ij=k$, etc., forms a group under multiplication. But what's the normal subgroup going to be? $ii=-1$, so any subgroup containing $i$ (or $ai$, or $aj$, or $ak$) will contain some reals.

Comment: Oops, I meant to write that $A_4$ has no subgroup of order *six*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy example to begin with, consider the dihedral group of order $8$ $$D_4=<s,r|,\, s^2=r^4=1,\, srs=r^{-1}>.$$
Put $N=<r>$. Because  $sr^ks= (srs)^k= r^{-k}\in N$, it follows $N$ is normal in $D_4$ (or because the index of $N$ in $D_4$ is $2$, and any subgroup of index $2$ is normal). Moreover $D_r/N\simeq <s>$ is abelian.

Edit: Sorry I didn't pay attention to the condition that $N$ must be non-abelian, so here a correction. Consider $D_6$ instead of $D_4$ where $$D_6=<s,r|,\, s^2=r^6=1,\, srs=r^{-1}>,$$
and let $N=<r^2,s>$. The rest is left for you.

Comment: The question asks for a proper non-abelian normal subgroup. Because the smallest non-abelian group has order $6$ the smallest possible order for an example is $12$. I am sure you can find an example (the dihedral group of order $12$ doesn't work as the subgroup of order $6$ is abelian).

Comment: @Mark, the dihedral group of order $12$ has more than one subgroup of order six.

Comment: @MarkBennet I didn't pay attention to the condition that $N$ must be non-abelian. Actually the dihedral group of order $12$ works very well.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, you are right.

Comment: @pigeon And you are right too.

Answer (score 1):

There is of course this set of examples: $G = S_n$ and $N = A_n$

Comment: $n \geq 3$, so that $A_n$ is not abelian.

Answer (score 1):

Take $N$ to be any non-abelian group and $A$ any (non-trivial) abelian group and $G$ = $A$ x $N$  (the subgroup is actually {$e$}x$N$, to be precise).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers, in the light of what you wrote earlier, I guess taking $G=Z_{2} \times S_{3}$ and $N=\{[0]\} \times S_{3}$ would suffice.